# what does >> do in actionscript 3.0?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

An example of it being used is here

```
boundsCentre = new Vector3D(stageWidth >> 1,stageHeight >> 1, 200.0);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`>>` is the right bit-shifting operator. `a >> b` will shift `a`'s bit values `b` bits to the right.

if `a = 8` and `b = 2`, `a >> b` will produce `2` because `a` is represented by `1000`, shifted 2 places is `10` which represents `2` in binary.

More importantly, because ActionScript is an ECMAScript variant, values of type `Number` will be converted from a 64-bit representation to a 32-bit representation and then shifted. Additionally, (AFAIK, can't seem to find it in the reference) bit-shift overflows are undefined in ECMAScript.

`stageWidth >> 1` essentially divides the stageWidth by 2, which means it's a vector to the center of the stage. In other languages `x >> 1` is a faster method of division by 2, but in ECMAScript, there is no significant performance change, and the possibility of ambiguity. Because of this it is better to just code the desired effect as:

```
stageWidth / 2
```

It is much more understandable that way.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bitwise right shift. See [this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html)

A bitwise right shift is, essentially, integer division by 2 for each position you shift. x >> 2 divides by 4, x >> 3 divides by 8, etc. Conversely, << is a left shift which is integer multiplication by 2.

Consider this example, the number 42 is, in binary

00101010

Right shifting by one position results in this:

00010101

Which is 21.

Comment: ah right, that makes sense. So I'm guessing its more efficient than using /2 ?

Comment: @Tim - I can't speak to that with authority in ActionScript, however in lower level languages like C or C++, if you're dividing or multiplying by a literal, that is x / 2 rather than x / y where y == 2, most compilers do generate more efficient code.

Comment: @Tim, in some languages it is, and so the common misconception is that it would be in ActionScript, but it's not, so it's not really as useful.

Comment: Shifting being more efficient than division in C is mostly a myth (or at least outdated).  Many modern compilers will optimize *2 and /2 into shifts, depending on compiler flags and target architecture.